# Is website deployed on Netlify from Github with autogenerated url being indexed by Google?

Tags: html, github, netlify

This could be a really dumb question but I wasn't able to find a proper answer on the internet.

I'm deploying a dev branch from my github repository in netlify just to test on different environment.
Netlify generates a custom nonsense url.

I don't want this deploy to be indexed by Google.

Is there an option I need to trigger to tell Netlify to hide the content from the search engines bots?

Something like

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

Would be the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but this is the same branch I use to throw files into my ftp to proper upload into my domain. 

I don't want to remove this line every time.
I was wondering if there is an option in Netlify to prevent indexing.